# Javascript on wordpress website page disappears as soon as I try to save it

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to insert JavaScript to a WordPress page. I added this to *functions.php*:

```
function add_custom_code() {
  if (is_front_page()) { ? >
    < script >
      (function() {
        var randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
        var targetElemId = ‘bcom_rwidget_’ + randomId;
        document.write(‘ < div id = ”‘+targetElemId + ‘” > < /div>‘);
        var script = document.createElement(‘script’);
        script.type = ‘text / javascript’;
        script.async = true;
        script.src = ‘http: //www.booking.com/review_widget/gb/the-manor-house-bed-amp-breakfast-enter code here`trunch.en.html?tmpl=review_widget/review_widget&wid=’ + targetElemId + ‘&wtype=box_small&hotel_id=XXXXX&`enter code here`widget_language=en’;
          var node = document.getElementsByTagName(‘script’)[0];
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node);
      }()); < /script> < ? php
  }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_code');
```

But when I add the script to the page, it disappears as soon as I
try to save it.

How can I run a secure JavaScript on a WordPress page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the javascript in a diffrent file, then enqueueing it in functions.php and calling it with  in case of front page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following..

**1. Using the `HTML` view of the WYSIWYG Editor.**

You need to change the writing mode from Visual to HTML and copy-paste your `JavaScript` code into the text box. There If you already have some content for the post, then you shall see the `HTML` for it, just type/paste your `js` at the bottom of the post content.

Remember to enclose the `js` code inside the `<style>` tags. This method will work most of the time, if it doesn't, then we have a plan B :)

**2. Using Custom Fields + Short Codes**

Here you create a new custom field and set the value of this custom field to the `JavaScript` code.  Then insert a `shortcode` in your post content which will in turn fetch the value of that custom field.